# Error with AWK command in ubuntu terminal

Tags: bash, awk

I am new in linux and AWK as well. I have a file in my home folder called *testing.txt* and i am trying to read the file using this awk command:

```
**arjun@arjun-Aspire-4741:~$ awk ´{print $1}´ testing.txt¨**
```

And I am getting this as output

```
**¨awk: ´{print
awk: ^ invalid char '�' in expression
arjun@arjun-Aspire-4741:~$ ¨**
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you've used forward ticks instead of quotes (in this case only single quotes are appropriate):

```
awk '{print $1}' testing.txt
```

instead of

```
awk ´{print $1}´ testing.txt
```

In shell, strings in double quotes `"` can contain expressions with special meaning (such as backticks, variables) which will be expanded before the string is processed as part of the full shell command. Strings in single quotes `'` are fully escaped; to put it another way, the string is passed literally without any interpretation. That's why you should use single quotes when writing awk scripts, because the awk variable dereference operator `$` is the same as in shell. There are no other valid string-delimiting characters*.

I initially thought you'd used backticks (thanks to Andras Deak for spotting my error).
Backticks have a special meaning in shell (equivalent to wrapping something in `$(...)`): execute this string as a command, and evaluate to its output (stdout). This is done *before* your main command is executed.

So, if I do

```
cat `echo myfile`
```

this turns into

```
cat myfile
```

which then executes.

You can read more about shell behaviour in a few places:

- http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sh.html
- http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/index.html

** ignoring that spaces are also technically string-delimiters*

Comment: Actually, OP seems to have *forward* ticks, for whatever reason, which explains why the error says `invalid char '�'` instead of something about a token or a command not found.

Comment: @AndrasDeak Well spotted! I've adjusted my answer appropriately.